# MongoDB DBRef handling inside GWT's RequestFactory function call

Tags: mongodb, gwt, reference, requestfactory, dbref

I have question related to DBRef of MongoDB. Imagine this scenario:

```
Group{
...
 "members" : [
            {
                    "$ref" : "User",
                    "$id" : ObjectId("505857a4e4b5541060863061")
            },
            {
                    "$ref" : "User",
                    "$id" : ObjectId("50586411e4b0b31012363208")
            },
            {
                    "$ref" : "User",
                    "$id" : ObjectId("50574b9ce4b0b3106023305c")
            },
]
...
}
```

So given group document has 3 user DBRef. Where in java class of Group, members is tagged with morphia as @Reference:

```
public class Group {

    ...

    @Reference
    List<User> members;

    ...

}
```

Question: When calling RequestFactory function getGroup().with("members") will RequestFactory get all members in ONLY 1 DB access ?

Or will Request factory make 3 DB access for each DBRef in Group document in the scenario given above?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

RequestFactory itself doesn't *access the DB*. What it'll do here is:

1. call `getMembers()`, as it was requested by the client through `.with("members")`
2. for each entity proxy seen (either in the request or in the response), call its locator's `isLive` method, or if has no `Locator`, call the entity's `findXxx` with its `getId()` (and check whether `null` is returned).

The first step depends entirely on Morphia's implementation:

- because you didn't set `lazy = true` on your `@Reference`, it won't matter whether RequestFactory calls `getMembers()` or not, the members will always be loaded.
- in any case (either eager or lazy fetching), it will lead to 4 Mongo queries (one to get the `Group` and another 3 for the members; I don't think Morphia tries to optimize the number of queries to only make 1 query to get all 3 members at a time)

The second step however depends entirely on your code.

Remember that RequestFactory wants you to have a single instance of an entity per HTTP request. As I understand it, Morphia has an `EntityCache` doing just that, but I suspect it could be bypassed by some methods/queries.